# Upload Image with SwiftUI and Directus

Tags: swiftui, directus

I want to send a UIImage retrieved from a PhotosPickerItem on my server, but I can't transform my image correctly to send it as a request

example of my code with which the image is not converted correctly, and the json is incorrect:

```
@MainActor
    private func postImage(token:Token, title:String, picture:UIImage) async {
        guard let urlRegister = URL(string: "https://serveurexemple/files") else {return}
        let pictureData = picture.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) ?? Data()
        var request = URLRequest(url: urlRegister)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token.access_token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let jsonObject:[String:Any] = ["title":title, "files":pictureData]
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [])
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        do {
            let (_,_) = try await session.data(for: request)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

the json is invalid, the error encountered is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
> reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Foundation.__NSSwiftData)' 
> *** First throw call stack: (0x1aa22ccb4 0x1a32cc3d0 0x1a450f52c 0x1a45a70fc 0x1a42b5974 0x1a4013bfc 0x1a4508e80 0x1a45323dc 0x1a4531e10 0x102ef82c0 0x102ef7725 0x103142371 0x10314194d 0x1031687dd 0x102d4a431 0x102d4a571 0x1b45e9dd9) libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: What is incorrect? How can you tell it is incorrect? Why are you ignoring all the errors and responses?

Comment: in other words, use `print(error)` and show us what it prints. Also `...example of my code with which the image is not converted correctly`, you mean `let pictureData = picture.jpegData(...)` does not work?

Comment: the json is invalid, the error encountered is: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Foundation.__NSSwiftData)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1aa22ccb4 0x1a32cc3d0 0x1a450f52c 0x1a45a70fc 0x1a42b5974 0x1a4013bfc 0x1a4508e80 0x1a45323dc 0x1a4531e10 0x102ef82c0 0x102ef7725 0x103142371 0x10314194d 0x1031687dd 0x102d4a431 0x102d4a571 0x1b45e9dd9)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException